# Comparing dates in Google Sheets QUERY() formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Looking for some assistance please.

To start, here's the function that I'm having trouble with:

```
=IFERROR(
  QUERY(
    OrderDetails!A8:Q9,
    "SELECT SUM(J) where Q >= date '" & TEXT(D3,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' label sum(J) ''"
  ),
  0
)
```

The dates in the data range (`OrderDetails!A8:Q9`, columns P is **Date** & Q is **DateOnly**) look like this:

[image: data range]

I added Q manually in an attempt to make the date-matching work, but P is the raw data which I would prefer to use.

Next the `SUM(J)` which are just order balances. If I remove the WHERE clause the query runs as expected.

D3 is the column date I want to match to, in the format: 8/13/2018, however I've formatted it on screen to be only DDD.

[image: D3 Date]

To show the actual value rather than the header in the cell, I've used `label sum(J) ' '`.

When running I get the message "Nothing to return".

Can anybody spot an obvious error with the code or my approach? Happy to add any further detail if needed.

Comment: have you tried datevalue(d3) where you have d3? It should be superfluous, but just in case?

Comment: I've just tried adding that in and I get an new error "DATEVALUE parameter '13' cannot be parsed to date/time." I assume the 13 is the day number and perhaps it's parsing in the wrong format or something.

Comment: That cell reference is incorrect, it should be D2, not D3. The new error is that it can't parse "Mon". I added the date unformatted in the style dd/mm/yyyy to a new row and removed the iferror check. and I get the same response as previously about "nothing to return".

Comment: It might be worth  (without surrounding query) checking that =TEXT(whichever it is now,"yyyy-mm-dd") is what you think it is. Maybe you already did that.

Comment: Yes, I did check. Thanks though. :)

 It's returning 2018-08-13 as expected.

Comment: I also tried "SELECT * where" vs "SELECT SUM(J) where" for the off chance that was causing it.

Comment: What do you get for =CELL("type", OrderDetails!Qsomething where there is a date)?

Comment: Or are you able to share a "view" link to the sheet so people can copy and play with it without your having to answer a slew of potentially annoying questions?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeremy. pnuts' answer seems to cover it. Still a little baffled but I'm up and running an that's what pays the bills! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Populate Q8 with:

```
=left(P8,10)*1
```

and copy down.

The QUERY is failing for attempting to compare a date (in D2/3) with the output of a *string* function (LEFT). `*1` coerces the strings into dates. Left alignment was a clue that the contents were Text.

Comment: Thanks pnuts. I had left(P8,10) but not with the *1 at the end.

Could you share what that does or point me at a learning resource?

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clue. Good one to keep in mind for future work.